# PHP: checking key value is not empty

Tags: php, arrays, key-value

I wrote a small function to check the required fields of a form, are not empty.
The function accepts two arguments, 1st is an array with all values from $_POST superglobal.
2nd is the required fields array which I populate.

Have a look:

```
public $errors = array();

public function validate_fields($fields_array, $required_fields) 
{
    foreach ($required_fields as $key => $value)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $fields_array)) 
        {
            # If key exists in $fields_array
            # check that the key value inside $fields_array is set & isn't empty
            # if it's empty, populate with an error
            if(empty($fields_array[$key][$value]))
            {
                $this->errors[] = "{$key} is empty but in fields_array";
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            # Key does not exists in $fields_array
            # Did someone temper with my html ?
            $this->errors[] = "{$key} is not in fields_array";
        }
    }
    return (empty($this->errors)) ? true : false;
}
```

The issue I'm having seems to be related to "if(empty($fields_array[$key][$value]))"
statement. my goal is to check that $fields_array key value is not empty based on $required_fields key. I'm sure the statement I'm using is off. If you see anything that you think can be written better, please let me know, as I am new to php. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you're trying to do is:

```
if(empty($fields_array[$key])) {
    //this means value does not exist or is FALSE
}
```

If you also want to check for empty-strings or white-space only, then you need something  more than just empty. E.g.

```
if(empty($fields_array[$key]) || !trim($fields_array[$key]))         {
    //this means key exists but value is null or empty string or whitespace only
}
```

Comment: Hi Richard, Thanks! I was unaware that empty is returning false on white spaces. Thanks again. By the way, this is how I populate the required fields array:  $required_fields = array("email" => "", "email_confirm" => ""); is there a faster approach to setting an array with just the key instead of defining key + empty value ?

Comment: $required_fields = array_fill_keys(array("email", "email_confirm","..."), "");

Comment: Thanks, that cleans it up a bit.

Answer (score 4):

Do note that the above answers will only work for indexed arrays in >PHP 5.4. If you have an associative array you have to use isset instead of empty:

```
if(isset($fields_array[$key]) && trim($fields_array[$key]) != '')
```

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php, example #2

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to select the value as an index just key.  Where $fields_array[$key] = $value;

```
if(empty($fields_array[$key]) && trim($fields_array[$key]) != '')
```

Comment: I see you added a few more conditions then Richard, wouldn't using empty and !trim cover everything I want to avoid? (any empty string or white spaces)

Comment: Just be careful with empty(), it treats things like 0 or "0" as 'empty', which may not be what you want in some cases. See the comments in http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php for more details. It's probably better to explicitly check for the conditions that you want.

Comment: I can't think of any reason I would expect users to input 0, "0", or even "-0" in a form. Even though I have 2 radio buttons for gender during register, I'll assign them to 1 & 2 in the db. If my logic is wrong, correct me :)

Comment: I would assign them to male/female or m/f.  Its easily readable even when looking at the db without any context.